# Error in Excel - #NAME? the error keep popping up and won't calculate the cost

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Alright, I know little to nothing about excel and this isn't even my job but someone pass it to me.
When inputting the cost and total cost the error `#NAME?` comes up.
In the column is put in

```
=@E46E48(
    G48B6=TRUE, 
    (
        @SWITCH(
            B36, "R22", "65",  "R410a", "50",  "R134a", "50", "R407c", "50", "RC404a", "50", "R123", "50", "R11", "85", "N/A", "0"
        )
    )*C36, 
    B6=FALSE, 
    (
        @SWITCH(
            B36, "R22", "75", "R410A", "60", "R134a", "60", "N/A", "0", "R123", "60", "R11", "95", "R404a", "60", "R407c", "60"
        )
    )*C36
)
```

(dont even know what that means)
I understand nothing and yeah. help if you can.

Comment: Show your input and desired output.

Comment: `@E46E48` is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of Formula auditing? In the "Formulas" menu, there's an "Evaluate Formula" menu option, where you can evaluate formulae step by step.

When pressing the "Evaluate" button, you already see that the first entry in your formula, `@E46E48`, is the one causing the problem:

[image]

What do you mean by that?